# How to combine the same date objects in one section?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, date

Now my tableView is sorted by date, but I also need to, if the dates are the same, connect them into one section. Please tell me how to do this?

```
class Transaction {
   var amount = "0"
   var date = Date()
   var note = ""
}
```

[image]

I want to make like on this image. 
[image]

After all upgradings result is former.

```
class OperationsViewController: UITableViewController {

var transactions: Results<Transaction>!
var dic = [String : [Transaction]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    transactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self)
    // transactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dic = Dictionary(grouping: transactions, by: {dateFormatter.string(from: $0.date) })
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super .viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

//  MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return dic.keys.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dic[Array(dic.keys)[section]]?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

 return ???
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "operationCell", for: indexPath) as! OperationsViewCell
    let keys = Array(dic.keys)
    let item = dic[keys[indexPath.section]]!
    let transaction = item[indexPath.row]

    cell.categoryLabel.text = transaction.category.rawValue
    cell.amountLabel.text = creatMathSymbols(indexPath) + transaction.amount + " " + "₴"
    cell.noteLabel.text = transaction.note

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Please add more code. Show how do you connect your model with `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: This is my code

Comment: How do you define `transactions`?

Comment: `transactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self)` in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: As I can guess on the attached screenshot there are `categoryLabel` and `noteLabel`. Where is `amountLabel`?

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193250/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-mikhail-tseitlin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an array

```
let arr = [Transaction]()  
let dic = Dictionary(grouping: arr, by: { $0.date})
```

`dic` will be `[Date:[Transaction]]` consider `date` key as section and value `[Transaction]` as sections rows

---

> numberOfsections

```
dic.keys.count
```

and

> numberofRows

```
let keys = Array(dic.keys)

let item = dic[keys[section]]!

return item.count
```

---

**Edit:**

```
let form = DateFormatter()
form.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let arr = [Transaction]()
let dic = Dictionary(grouping: arr, by: {form.string(from: $0.date)})
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193266/discussion-on-answer-by-sh-khan-how-to-combine-the-same-date-objects-in-one-sect).