# Creating Table View with cells separated by dates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm playing around with TableViews and making lists. However, one thing I'm completely lost in knowing how to do is creating a List of tasks that are separated by dates.

For example, if I needed to call a friend on June 15 to wish him happy birthday; instead of the tableCell telling me to call him it would be separated by that date.

Something like this: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjq7YHgvpniAhWRu54KHX7-BMoQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fappadvice.com%2Fapp%2Ftower-radio-app%2F1405371224&psig=AOvVaw1Q57CGOQFZ6xm9SG9zHgqK&ust=1557870701032787

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109447/how-to-combine-the-same-date-objects-in-one-section

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the dates in the section, and the tasks are already in the cells. roughly so:

```
import UIKit

struct ToDo {
   let date: Double
   let todo: [String]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var array: [ToDo] = [ToDo(date: 1560640981, todo: ["call a friend to wish him happy birthday"]), ToDo(date: 1557962581, todo: ["Buy mom flowers", "By milk"])]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array[section].todo.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let dateInUnix = array[section].date
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dateInUnix)

        let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd YYYY hh:mm a"
        let dateString = dayTimePeriodFormatter.string(from: date)

        return dateString
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.array[indexPath.section].todo[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

And you will get something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlQlR.png)